# Vertically align multiple images within a div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align/center some images within a div. It`s not 100% correct. The images are some pixels too much down to be vertically centered. Why is that?

```
.Container
{   
    width:280px;
    position:fixed;
    border:1px solid blue;
    left:0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:84px;
}

.Container input[type=image]
{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/2j531q32/

update 2: The images are not valid int the js fiddle
There you see the gap between the image and the top border.

Comment: Can you post your HTML or make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) showing your problem?

Comment: gimme a second I do a fiddle...

Comment: Are you sure the images simply don't have something about them that just 'makes' them look off center? For instance white background at the bottom of the image  on a white background of the page could make it look funky.

Comment: I updated my init post with a fiddle.

Comment: Have you tried this resource? http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: @WillemEllis yes I already use a fixed line-height.

Comment: seems to be a strange layout problem, maybe browser specific?
try this, it works in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/eY7Ms/7/

Comment: @r3bel http://jsfiddle.net/eY7Ms/9/ they are not vertically centered. There seems to be more space between the top edge of the image and the top div.

Comment: Are you trying to vertically align the images side by side or one each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for any line height css. You can vertically align divs using the `display:table` and `display:table-cell` styles. The height of `.ButtonBarDiv` has been exaggerated to show that they both center vertically.

One image per line:
http://jsfiddle.net/eY7Ms/16/

Images on the same line:
http://jsfiddle.net/eY7Ms/14/

Comment: Thanks Omega, I used your code and changed my sample to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/eY7Ms/23/

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution didn't work for me in IE11.

I found a great page of [Method for Vertical Centering](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).

This works for me in Chrome and IE11 
The line-height needs to be > the highest element to be centered.

```
#Parent{
    line-height: 200px; // > the highest element to be centered.
}

.parent img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Jsfiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/zewhr2jq/)

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found another question on stackoverflow:
[Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

It seems like browsers render an extra space above / below a line, so you might want to ajust the line-height, here is an exmaple:

http://jsfiddle.net/eY7Ms/13/

so if you want to adjust the vertical extra space, you might do something like that:

```
.boxWithVerticalCenteredContent {
    height: 4em;
    line-height: 3.6em;
}
```

i know, this is not perfectly centered and it is fixed in height, but if you want to center it absolute, you might want to use `position: absolute` and `top, bottom, left, right`

Answer (score 0):

Will only work in modern browsers but:

```
.elementToAlign{
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform : translateY(-50%);
}
```